# How can I show data after searching it from database using node.js in back-end?

Tags: sql, node.js

I have a database where I store the medicine list. My website contains a search box. Now I wanted to search medicine from database and wanted to display the result in my site. To do so I wanted to use node.js in back-end. So, I need the steps for making my work out. Can anyone please help me with proper steps which should I follow to do my work?

Comment: Hi and welcome, as it stands your question is way to broad, please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please add details (possibly some code) on what you have tried so far, for people to actually help you. Otherwise your question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Step # 1: read documentation on node.js + mySQL

Step # 2: see examples of code

Step # 3: try it yourself

Step # 4: if you are stuck - come and ask relevant question of what you did, what you expected and what is result